# PDO prepared и функции

Tags: php, ооп, pdo

В общем, такая проблема. PDO не видит объекта при вызове запроса функцией. 
Сначала было так:

```
<?php
include 'pdoconnect.php';
function get_block($name){
$prepare = $db->prepare("SELECT `code` from `items` where `name = $name");  
$prepare->execute();
$item = $prepare->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$user_menu = $item[`code`];
return $user_menu
}

function check_user_menu(){
if (empty($_SESSION['login'])){
$name = "user_menu1";
get_block($name);
}else{
$name = "user_menu2";
get_block($name);
}
}

?>
```

Выкинуло:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
> prepare() on a non-object

Начал эксперементировать, решил биндить данные (да-да, тапками не кидайтесь).

Т.е. строка запроса изменилась на

```
   $prepare = $db->prepare("SELECT `code` from `items` where `name = :name");
```

И добавилось:

```
$prepare->bindParam(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Потом исправил на:

```
$prepare = $db->exec("SELECT `code` from `items` where `name` = $name");
```

Однако - та же песня.

Уважаемые, что я мог опять сделать не так?

Comment: @Виталий RS, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Answer (score 2):

```
function get_block($name){
$prepare = $db->prepare("SELECT `code` from `items` where `name = $name");
```

ну и откуда здесь $db-то появится?

> Начал эксперементировать, решил биндить данные (да да, тапками не кидайтесь).

Я скорее тапком кину за исходный вариант.

Comment: @Etki $db появилось из заинклуженого файла pdoconnect.php, в самой первой строке

Comment: @Виталий RS, ну вы же в курсе, что php это совсем не яваскрипт и не умеет самостоятельно смотреть из функции во внешнюю область видимости?

Comment: @Etki, окей, инклуд занес внутрь, теперь выкидывает  Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object
Ладно, fetch с таким запросом не работает. Но вот ни errorinfo(), ни print_r ничего не возвращают.
А var_dump отдал bool(false).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы переменная была видна внутри функции, можно использовать оператор `global`. Правильный код будет выглядеть так:

```
<?php
include 'pdoconnect.php';

function get_block($name){
    global $db;
    $prepare = $db->prepare("SELECT `code` from `items` where `name` = ?");  
    $prepare->execute([$name]);
    return $prepare->fetchColumn();
}
```